# My hamburger menu displays incorrectly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I have this weird issue that is happening with my hamburger menu using Bootstrap. It is stretching it out to the right, I have no idea why. It looks fine in the attached snippet editor, my picture is below. Any idea on what can cause this?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav id="mynav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" alt=""/>&#160;<span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-1-0 ms-rteFontSize-4 ms-rteFontFace-5"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Site 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Site 4</a></li></ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[image: image of the correctly displayed hamburger menu]

Comment: In scenarios like this; the fastest route is to use the inspector.  Right click on the button and click "inspect" in Chrome.  Look for either a margin / padding on any span / a / nav or image.  With a link to the example further details can be given.

Comment: Can you add a picture of console while inspecting .navba-toggle..also add the image of associated css.

Comment: I added image of the inspected console

Comment: @neophyte image has been added

Comment: can you share the image of button.navbar-toggle.collapsed related css which you can see in the console..then we can debug it.

Comment: @neophyte the css above is the collapsed code

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be called something like '.navbar-toggle', so look for this and amend the padding or margin. If you can't see any padding or margin, try adding it with 0px !important.

Comment: as a test, i tried hiding  .navbar-toggle in the css and nothing happens.

Comment: When you say you hid it in the css, what did you exactly do to it?

Comment: changed the css to .navbar-toggle.collapsed{ display:none !important;}

Comment: Try doing the same to navbar-toggle with no 'collapsed'?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely coming from your bootstrap CSS or any other 'template' style CSS includes. Try locating the [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) using a 'inspect tool' *ie*. Google [Chrome Developer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) Console or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or IE Developer tools if you must. Locate the element's selector with the incorrect width, and set your desired width within CSS manually to that selector. *ie.*

```
.relevantSelector { 
   max-width: $maxwidth;
   min-width: $minwidth;
   width: $width;
}
```

You could also check and toggle the `padding:` or any `margin:` properties set to see if this fixes it. But, this is definitely a CSS issue. If you don't want to do above, try disabling some of your CSS properties via 'inspect tools' above or even entire stylesheets and CSS, to see if by doing so it goes back to a correct width and you can isolate your conflict.

Comment: toggle padding by .nav-bar-toggle{ padding:10px;} is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, try different values or hiding properties to see if it looks better or snaps back to correct width.